The limiting position of a point at which the bisector of an angle intersect with its opposite side
This is a problem in a textbook:

(a) The figure shows an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with $\angle B = \angle C$. The bisector of angle $B$ intersects the side $AC$ at the point $P$. Suppose that the base $BC$ remains fixed but the altitude $|AM|$ of the triangle approaches $0$, so $A$ approaches the midpoint $M$ of $BC$. What happens to $P$ during this process? Does it have a limiting position? If so, find it.
(b) Try to sketch the path traced out by $P$ during this process. Then find an equation of this curve and use this equation to sketch the curve.
This is what I have done:

(a) Take $M$ as the origin, $BC$ as the $x$-axis, $AM$ as the $y$-axis to establish a right-angle coordinate system, let $OB = OC = a$, $\angle ABC = \theta$, then the equation of the line where $BP$ is located is
$$ y_1=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}x+a\tan\frac{\theta}{2} $$
The equation of the line where $AC$ is located is
$$ y_2=-\tan\theta x+a\tan\theta $$
Let $y_1=y_2$, we can get
$$ x=\frac{a(\tan\theta-\tan\frac{\theta}{2})}{\tan\theta+\tan\frac{\theta}{2}} $$
$$ \lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{a(\tan\theta-\tan\frac{\theta}{2})}{\tan\theta+\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{a(\sec^2\theta-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{\theta}{2})}{\sec^2\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{\theta}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}a $$
So, the limiting position of $P$ is $(\frac{1}{3}a,\,0)$.
(b) Substitute the formula about $x$ above to any of these two lines, we get a parametric equation with respect to $\theta$：
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{a(\tan\theta-\tan\frac{\theta}{2})}{\tan\theta+\tan\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
y=a\tan\theta\left(1-\frac{\tan\theta-\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{\tan\theta+\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)
\end{cases}
$$
I use python to draw its graph when $a=1$ and it's consistent with what I've observed in Geogebra animation.


But I think I overthought this and it shouldn't be so complicated. Is there another easier way to solve this problem?

Question already asked here but without true answer. See also here.

By the angle bisector theorem,
$$\frac{PC}{AP}=\frac{BC}{AB}\implies\frac{AC}{AP}-1=\frac{2a}{\frac{a}{\cos\theta}}=2\cos\theta\implies AP=\frac{AC}{1+2\cos\theta}=\frac{a\sec\theta}{1+2\cos\theta}$$
$$\color{red}x=AP\cos\theta=\color{red}{\frac{a}{1+2\cos\theta}}\to\color{blue}{\frac a3}\qquad\text{as}~\color{blue}{\theta\to0}$$
$$\color{red}y=AM-AP\sin\theta=a\tan\theta-\frac{a\tan\theta}{1+2\cos\theta}=\color{red}{\frac{2a\sin\theta}{1+2\cos\theta}}\to\color{blue}0\qquad\text{as}~\color{blue}{\theta\to0}$$
which is the required curve equation in the parametric form with a parameter $\theta$.
The limiting position of $P$: $\color{blue}{(x_0,y_0)=\left(\frac a3,0\right)}$ as $A\to M$ or $\theta\to0$.
The curves or loci of $P$ shown in the image are plotted using the Desmos graphing calculator. The equal angles in all the isosceles triangles are $70^\circ$, and half of the base are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ units.


We are going to show that the locus of point $P$ is an arc of hyperbola with equation :
$$3x^2-y^2+2x-1=0\tag{1}$$
(valid for $x \in (0,1)$).

Fig. 1 : The locus is arc $P_0P_1$ on the right branch of the hyperbola.
As a consequence, the limit point when $A$ tends to $M$ is the point with $y=0$ which is the positive root of quadratic equation
$$3x^2+2x-1=0\tag{1'}$$
which is $x=\frac13$.
Proof of equation (1):
Let $B(-1,0), C(1,0), P=(x,y)$ and let $H$ be the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto the $x$-axis.
Let $ \theta:=\angle CBA=\angle ACB$ (your notation).
In right triangles $PHB$ and $PHC$ resp., we have :
$$\tan \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{PH}{BH}= \frac{y}{x+1} \ \text{and} \ \tan \theta=\frac{PH}{HC} =\frac{y}{1-x}\tag{2}$$
Plugging expressions (2a) and (2b) into the classical formula :
$$\tan \theta= \frac{2 \tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1-\left(\tan \frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2},$$
gives expression (1).
Remarks :



We have seen the limit position $P_0 (1/3,0)$ for $P$ ; the other limit position is $P_1(1,2)$.




Equation (1) can be written under the equivalent form



$$\underbrace{(1-x)^2+y^2}_{dist(P,C)^2}=\underbrace{4}_{e^2} \underbrace{x^2}_{dist(P,(Oy))^2}$$
allowing to make the connection with the geometrical definition of a hyperbola in terms of its focus $C(1;0)$ and its directrix, the ordinate axis $Oy$ ; moreover, its eccentricity is $e=2$.

(+1) Nice! Even I guessed it would be hyperbola after eliminating $\theta$.
